# How to install rails in Ubuntu 16 OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginner of learning rails. I want to install rails5 in my Linux operating system.
How can I install rails in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to install some dependencies for Ruby.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev nodejs
```

Install rbenv and ruby:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.4.0
rbenv global 2.4.0
ruby -v
```

The last step is to install Bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

Install nodejs:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Install rails now:

```
gem install rails -v 5.0.1
```

you'll need to run the following command to make the rails executable available:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Now that you've installed Rails, you can run the `rails -v` command to make sure you have everything installed correctly:

```
rails -v
# Rails 5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install Rails. It's a virtualization system that will allow you to install multiple versions of Ruby, and maintain different sets of libraries (including Rails) for each project you work on. By default, it installs Rails and its libraries (gems) in your user directory. This is both safer (more secure) than system-wide installation, and much more flexible.

You could install Rails via Ubuntu's package manager (`sudo apt-get install rails`), and install its libraries via the system-wide RubyGems installer (`gem`), but that's not a best-practice. While Ruby and Rails don't change as often as they did a few years ago, the dev ecosystem still evolves faster than Linux distributions like Ubuntu can keep up with.

These days, everyone developing Rails apps uses either RVM or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage user-space installations. There's no compelling reason to prefer RVM or rbenv as you start out, but RVM is more popular.